# CGI - FieldStorage - Data from field storage returns a MiniFieldStorage

Tags: python, html, forms, cgi

I have an HTML form which returns a submits a single value. The code for which is as below:

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/filter.cgi" method = "get">Filter By Version: <input    type="text" name="filter"/><input type="submit" value="submit"/></form>
```

The CGI is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
formData = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

When I print the value of formData. I get the following output:

**FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('filter', '112')])**

How can I get the information of "filter"? Why am I getting the value in "MINIFIELDSTORAGE"?

Comment: read `CGI` doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read `CGI` doc: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/cgi.html

You have

```
value = formData['filter'].value 
value = formData.getvalue('filter')
value = formData.getvalue('filter', default_value)
```

and many other methods to get value.

---

In doc:

> ... are themselves instances of FieldStorage (or MiniFieldStorage, **depending on the form encoding**)

and

> When a form is submitted in the “old” format (**as the query string** or as a single data part of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded), the items will actually be instances of the class MiniFieldStorage.

`query string` means `method="GET"` instead of `method="POST"`